# SQL: right syntax to use near

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, node-mysql

I use a package `mysql` for the NodeJS for working the MySQL.
I want to check the data. I write next a query and then save it in declared variable:

```
SELECT username, email FROM `Users` WHERE `username` = ' + user.username + 'AND `email` = ' + user.email + ')
```

and below an object which should be add in my the DB:

```
const user = {
 'username': username,
 'password': bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null),
 'email': req.body.email
};
```

But, I get an error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`email` = example@gmail.com)' at line 1
```

Please, tell to me when I made the error or the errors.

Comment: Learn to use parameters rather than munging string names.  It prevents syntax errors and SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Many thanks. I changed the sql-query.